# Library missing for executable file

Tags: 10.04, bash, executable, shared-library

There's an executable I downloaded onto my Ubuntu 10.04 and I can't run because it's missing a library. I have also tried compiling the source with CMake. This is my Terminal output:

```
zack@zack-laptop:~/Desktop$ ./MultiMC
./MultiMC: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I think I need libssl 1.0 to run this file, but I'm not sure. Any help?

@Jim Salter: The output of `lsb_release -d ; apt-file update ; apt-file search libssl.so.1.0.0` is:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
apt-file is now using the user's cache directory.
If you want to switch back to the system-wide cache directory,
 run 'apt-file purge'
Downloading complete file http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 16.8M  100 16.8M    0     0   275k      0  0:01:02  0:01:02 --:--:--  171k
Downloading complete file http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15.4M  100 15.4M    0     0   228k      0  0:01:09  0:01:09 --:--:--  346k
Downloading Index http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Contents-i386.diff/Index:
No Index available.
Downloading complete file http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
File is up-to-date.
Downloading Index http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/Contents-i386.diff/Index:
No Index available.
Downloading complete file http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 15.4M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
File is up-to-date.
Downloading Index http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Contents-i386.diff/Index:
No Index available.
Downloading complete file http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
File is up-to-date.
Downloading Index http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/Contents-i386.diff/Index:
No Index available.
Downloading complete file http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-updates/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
File is up-to-date.
Ignoring source without Contents File:
  http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Contents-i386.gz
Downloading complete file http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.2M  100 12.2M    0     0   303k      0  0:00:41  0:00:41 --:--:--  367k
Downloading Index http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/Contents-i386.diff/Index:
No Index available.
Downloading complete file http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 12.2M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
File is up-to-date.
Downloading Index http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/Contents-i386.diff/Index:
No Index available.
Downloading complete file http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/Contents-i386.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 12.2M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
File is up-to-date.
Ignoring source without Contents File:
  http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Contents-i386.gz
Ignoring source without Contents File:
  http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Contents-i386.gz
```

Comment: You might want to clarify your question by possibly explaining what the executable is and provide a link from where you downloaded it and the steps that you have already taken. If this is the MultiMC application, what version did you download? Did your MONO pre-reqs install ok?

Comment: @maggotbrain I already had MONO, I downloaded the latest version availible from [here](http://forkk.net/MultiMC4/), and I have also tried compiling the source with CMake, which didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`you@box:~$ locate libssl.so.1.0.0`

On my machine, this returns `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0`.  So.  This thing you're trying to run - is it 32-bit code, or 64-bit code?  Assuming it's the former:

```
you@box:~/Desktop$ mkdir ~/MultiMC
you@box:~/Desktop$ mv MultiMC ~/MultiMC
you@box:~/Desktop$ cd ~/MultiMC
you@box:~/MultiMC$ ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 ./
you@box:~/MultiMC$ ./MultiMC
```

And Bob should be your uncle.  (The problem is that your "MultiMC" doesn't know where to look for the library, even though it's actually present on your system.  In theory, if you have access to the source code - or if this is just a script to begin with - you could also just edit the application itself to look for the library in the right place.)

What if you DON'T have `libssl.so.1.0.0` in the first place?  Well, in this case you almost certainly do.  But maybe there'll be ANOTHER library it needs and can't find after you satisfy this one, and you turn out not to already have that one...

```
you@box:~/MultiMC$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
you@box:~/MultiMC$ sudo apt-file update
you@box:~/MultiMC$ sudo apt-file search libssl.so.1.0.0
```

And you can then install whatever package contains the library you need.  **Always check first to see if you already have the library and just don't know where to find it, though!** =)

Comment: I had no output of both `sudo apt-file search libssl.so.1.0.0` and `locate libssl.so.1.0.0`

Comment: That's surprising.  Did you remember to **apt-file update** first?

Please post entire output of `lsb_release -d ; apt-file update ; apt-file search libssl.so.1.0.0` - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, try running this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

If you are running multiarch, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl1.0.0:i386
```

See if it works :)

Comment: Nope, I already tried that.

Comment: libssl1.0.0:i386 was the missing package for me...